# What do you call debris and other things that prevent you from moving through something?

Tags: word-request

I thought the word was drudges, but it means menial work.

> I walked through the ___ in the swamp.
>
> The ___ slowed down my movement as I walked through the swamp.

It sounds like drudges, but doesn't mean the same thing. Can't find the word.

Comment: Are you looking for [detritus](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/detritus) by any chance?

Comment: Maybe sludge would fit.

Comment: impediments, hindrances, obstacles, blockages, entanglements, tangle, mire, bog, quag... or you could get specific and say something like, "the sphagnum mosses, sedge, and tangling branches and roots of stunted black spruce and tamarack trees filling the boggy murk."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Debris' or obstacles(more figurative) would work
Dredging is clearing a channel for ships.

You're correct a drudge is an old fashioned word for a menial worker.
Maybe you're thinking of 'sludge'? Which would be a little off.